# Automagic Link Shortening for Non-Hosted WP

Tags: plugins, customization, plugin-recommendation

Blogs hosted on wordpress.com get automatic link shortening via http://wp.me/, but for those who prefer to seek out our own hosting solution is there a plugin that will, upon publishing a new post/page, make an api call to bit.ly (or other such service) store the resulting url and return it from `wp_get_shortlink()`?

I have searched without success. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-bitly/

Answer (score 3):

if you install the wordpress.com stats plugin on your self hosted wordpress blog, you will have the option to have wp.me shortlinks

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stats/

Answer (score 1):

You could also add something like this to your functions.php to add a short link (powered by tinyurl) to each post or page you have:

```
function shortLink($content) {
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$short_url = file_get_contents('http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url='.urlencode($url));

$content .=  '<div class="short-link">Here's a short link <a href=".$short_url.'">Short Link</a></div>';

return $content;
```

}

add_filter('the_content', 'shortLink');